# Ticket Tailor API issue

Tags: javascript, axios, cors, fetch-api

I want to make a fetch request to this API https://api.tickettailor.com/v1/events, I have a valid API key and it works at Postman, but when I want to make the same request via browser, I get a CORS error and I don't understand why.

I have tried different ways, with axios, fetch, etc. It doesn't work.

```
const headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
    };

    const auth = {
      username: MY_API_KEY,
      // username: this.state.apiKey,
      password: "",
    };

    const url = "https://api.tickettailor.com/v1/ping";

    axios
      .get(url, {
        Accept: "application/json",
        auth: auth,
      })
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CORS` error is from the server because it doesn't allow your origin to request.

Postman doesn't error because Postman ignore `CORS` header.

You either have to ask `TicketTailor` about your issue or use a proxy server to bypass the `CORS`.

The best way is to ask about your issue because proxy server makes your request slower and if you don't use a trusted proxy server they can log and stole your api key.